# In Binance spot trades data, what is it meant by 'price' field?

Tags: crypto-exchanges

Surely, if a trade was of large quantity, it most likely wasn't filled at a single price.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#recent-trades-list

Comment: Have you tried asking Binance customer support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular API, but in general, such a trade will be counted as multiple smaller trades.

That is, suppose you place an limit order for 1000 units at $1. It might be partially filled by trades of 300 units at $0.98, then 300 units at $0.99, and finally 400 units at $1.00. Those are three separate trades.